# Search array parts by partial in some property

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this kind of object in typescript

```
const photos = 
  {
  "albumId": "1",
  "title": "quidem molestiae enim",
  "created": "1",
  "photos": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "title": "sunset",
      "url": "https://via.placeholder.com/600/92c952",
      "thumbnailUrl": "https://via.placeholder.com/150/92c952"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "title": "today is sunshine",
      "url": "https://via.placeholder.com/600/771796",
      "thumbnailUrl": "https://via.placeholder.com/150/771796"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "title": "test",
      "url": "https://via.placeholder.com/600/24f355",
      "thumbnailUrl": "https://via.placeholder.com/150/24f355"
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to push out all values that are not find in string, search in performed in photos.photos.title.
Here is example, lets say i have a string like this

```
const searchText = 'sun';
```

I need to serach inside photos.photos.title and remove all photos.photos that does not contais part of that word.My ne photos should look like this

```
const photos = 
  {
  "albumId": "1",
  "title": "quidem molestiae enim",
  "created": "1",
  "photos": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "title": "sunset",
      "url": "https://via.placeholder.com/600/92c952",
      "thumbnailUrl": "https://via.placeholder.com/150/92c952"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "title": "today is sunshine",
      "url": "https://via.placeholder.com/600/771796",
      "thumbnailUrl": "https://via.placeholder.com/150/771796"
    }
  ]
}
```

You will see that all remaining photos member is left, because in title they having a part of word **sun**

I dont know how even to start, i know i can do find, but i need to search only part of the word not entire word? It can not just be last memmber of the array, the array is much bigger :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `filter()` on `photos.photos` and check that if `title` contains `'sun'` using `includes()`

```js
const photos = { "albumId": "1", "title": "quidem molestiae enim", "created": "1", "photos": [ { "id": "1", "title": "sunset", "url": "https://via.placeholder.com/600/92c952", "thumbnailUrl": "https://via.placeholder.com/150/92c952" }, { "id": "2", "title": "today is sunshine", "url": "https://via.placeholder.com/600/771796", "thumbnailUrl": "https://via.placeholder.com/150/771796" }, { "id": "3", "title": "test", "url": "https://via.placeholder.com/600/24f355", "thumbnailUrl": "https://via.placeholder.com/150/24f355" } ] }
let str = "sun"
photos.photos = photos.photos.filter(x => x.title.includes(str))
console.log(photos)
```